# Prevent access to $_SESSION, $_SERVER, $_POST, $_GET, $_REQUEST

Tags: php

I am considering building a new PHP application, which would allow for new modules to be added. As I am still in early phase considering design structure and security, a question came to mind:

Could I prevent third party modules to access $_ variables (`$_SESSION`, `$_SERVER`, etc) except through some controller class that is core to the app? If this is possible, how can I achieve it?

Comment: You can. You can just copy them into your favorite data structure and then unset them. But then what? Shouldn't it be up to the user? When building a new application or framework, maybe you should consider possibilities first instead of adding limitations.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned by others, at the entry point of your application you copy these superglobals to the properties of some object(s), then unset them. You can now pass the object(s) to methods that you want access to them.

Comment: Wouldn't unsetting them cause other issues with php session? I did consider unsetting them all but i don't know enough of the innerworkings of the PHP session and how the server works to know whether that would cause issues (specially regarding $_SERVER)

Comment: @GolezTrol This wouldn't affect the user - only developers of add-in modules - the way i see it this would actually make things more secure to end users by having my app control what information each module has access to and can change. Otherwise a module could be created to impersonate a logged user by creating the apropriate session variables

Comment: @537mfb In the context of a plugin system, the programmer writing the plugin is the user of the system.

Comment: Why the downvotes? perfectly legitimate question  here

Comment: Your application code should just load the session variables on startup and not re-load them again. Then plugins can set them, but it leads to nothing, since the application core doesn't use those globals anymore. If you want to clear them as well is up to you, then.

Comment: @GolezTrol - i will also need to persist the data for each session somehow too - preferably in some way that a 3rd party module wouldn't have access to or all that work would have been for not. A database is an option - but i would need to encrypt the data in a way that was both secure and reversable - all things i am thinking about

Comment: @GolezTrol `In the context of a plugin system, the programmer writing the plugin is the user of the system` I see your point - But IMO the core app should ALWAYS control what any third party has access to in regards to data - otherwise you could be opening a can of worms - see my exemple of the logged user impursonation. This type of thing needs to be pevent for end user safety

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up an input class that reads these values in and then resets them to an empty `array()` prior to your controllers seeing them. Controllers will still be able to access them, but they will not be able to retrieve any input from them. Thus, they will be forced to go to your input object to get user input.

If your purpose in doing this is XSS filtering, it's worth bearing in mind that often you will need to handle tainted data (i.e. containing the dangerous characters `<>'"`). In those circumstances you might need something like this:

```
$inputHolder->getRawValue('comment');
```

and in the usual case (especially for integers etc, where dangerous character filtering is welcome):

```
$inputHolder->getValue('page');
```

I've not used it, but I noticed that the popular PHP framework CodeIgniter offers a [similar feature to this](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html).

It's worth being aware of the counterargument to this approach - some people would say that it is the wrong place to be doing this filtering. In an ideal world, you'd handle tainted input in your controller, pass it to your view/template layer, and escape it there (e.g. with `htmlentities()`). Or, you'd untaint/cast it in your controller so that it is safe for rendering without escaping.

It is however always possible to miss something, especially in big applications. Thus, perhaps having the option is a good thing: security by default, raw input with deliberate effort. This makes me wonder, then, whether the parameter options in the CI class are the right way around - take a look.

Comment: Wouldn't unsetting them cause other issues with php session? I did consider unsetting them all but i don't know enough of the innerworkings of the PHP session and how the server works to know whether that would cause issues (specially regarding $_SERVER)

Comment: Just read the site you link to - really cool - unless someone comes up with a better one i'll give you this

Comment: @537mfb, yes I might be cautious about clearing `$_SERVER`. What in it can be tainted? Certainly the USER_AGENT, not sure about anything else? AS I say, I would reset them to an empty array, **not** unset them.

Comment: am not just thinking about tainted stuff in considering this approach - am also considering end user security. I don't rightly see a case for $_SERVER but for exemple i want to prevent a 3rd party module from impersonating a logged user by inituializing the correct variables in $_SESSION (example) - although $_SERVER does contain identifying data (like remnote IP) that could (should?) be protected from 3rd party for user security

Comment: @537mfb: if you are allowing non-trusted developers to run code here, the only things you can rely on are trusting those devs (e.g. they have a valuable brand they wish to protect) or code review.

Comment: The idea is to have my app extendable with modules - i intend to build modules for it but i did't want to prevent anyone else from building theyr own customized modules for their own needs - probably even selling them - i just want to make sure i am doing all i can to protect end users from ill intended people

Comment: `the only things you can rely on are trusting those devs (...) or code review` - Code review isn't much of na option as i will likelly not have control on where those modules get sold/distributed (3rd party after all). And trusting 3rd party devs doesn't mean you should neglect security. It only means you're not placing yourself in the part of the policeman inspecting all their code like you expect them to be up to no good. If there are things you can secure you should secure it - for end users sake. All it takes is one ill intended person to exploit a security hole.

Comment: @537mfb: it sounds like you're doing something similar to Wordpress plugins. There is a good understanding in that ecosystem that where a plugin is new or has a low number of reviews, it has been available for long enough to garner trust. Adding security is right up to a point, but it could offer a false level of security - your users come to expect that the level of isolation you offer is a guarantee of security, and of course that is not the case.